# reCaptcha always return false when verifying it with Google

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, recaptcha

After I get the response token `g-recaptcha-response`, I verify it with reCAPTCHA like this :

```
@Service
public class RecaptchaService {

    private static class RecaptchaResponse {
        @JsonProperty("success")
        private boolean success;
        @JsonProperty("error-codes")
        private Collection<String> errorCodes;
    }

    @Value("${recaptcha.url}")
    private String recaptchaUrl;

    @Value("${recaptcha.secret-key}")
    private String recaptchaSecretKey;


    public boolean isResponseValid(String response) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("secret", recaptchaSecretKey);
        params.put("response", response);


        RecaptchaResponse recaptchaResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity( recaptchaUrl, params, RecaptchaResponse.class).getBody();

        return recaptchaResponse.success;

    }

}
```

But I Get always `false` as `recaptchaResponse.success` and `[missing-input-response, missing-input-secret]` as `error-codes`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but its an easy fix. I'll explain the fix and then try to explain the problem.

The easiest way to fix this is to append the parameters to the URL and pass a null for the 'Object request'. I've changed your code to demonstrate the change.

```
@Service
public class RecaptchaService {

    private static class RecaptchaResponse {
        @JsonProperty("success")
        private boolean success;
        @JsonProperty("error-codes")
        private Collection<String> errorCodes;
    }

    @Value("${recaptcha.url}")
    private String recaptchaUrl;

    @Value("${recaptcha.secret-key}")
    private String recaptchaSecretKey;

    public boolean isResponseValid(String response) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        recaptchaUrl = new StringBuilder()
                .append(recaptchaUrl)
                .append("?secret=")
                .append(recaptchaSecretKey)
                .append("&response=")
                .append(response)
                .toString();

        RecaptchaResponse recaptchaResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(recaptchaUrl, null, RecaptchaResponse.class).getBody();
        return recaptchaResponse.success;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. The reason I moved the parameters from the Hashmap to the URL is because RestTemplate was converting the Hashmap parameters to JSON format. Recaptcha didn't understand the parameters in JSON format. Moving the parameters to the URL was easy and worked.